# Spark Streaming doesn't receive any data from Flume

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, flume

I created a simple spark streaming application to consume data from Flume using Pull-based approach.

```
Spark version: 2.2.0
Flume version: 1.7.0
```

It works well when I run the program from my PC in Eclipse (Run As - Scala Application). But after compiling it into jar and submit the app via spark-submit, it's not receiving any data from Flume. Here's my code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]){
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("twitter").set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true")
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(30))
  val flumeStream = FlumeUtils.createPollingStream(ssc, "172.31.190.31", 9999)
  val tweets = flumeStream.map(e => new String(e.event.getBody.array()))
  tweets.print()
  tweets.foreachRDD(rdd=>{
    rdd.saveAsTextFile("/warehouse/raw/twitter/data")
  })
  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

I build the program via Right Click the project - Run As - Maven Build - Goals=package - Run.

And here's how I submit the app:

```
spark-submit --master local[*] --deploy-mode client --class co.id.linknet.general.StreamingFlume ./spark/lib/linknet-general-1.0.1.jar
```

Flume config:

```
TwitterAgent01.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent01.channels = MemoryChannel01
TwitterAgent01.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent01.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent01.sources.Twitter.channels = MemoryChannel01
TwitterAgent01.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxx
TwitterAgent01.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxx
TwitterAgent01.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxx
TwitterAgent01.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxx
TwitterAgent01.sources.Twitter.keywords = keyword1, keyword2, keywordN

TwitterAgent01.sinks = sparkStream
TwitterAgent01.sinks.sparkStream.type = org.apache.spark.streaming.flume.sink.SparkSink
TwitterAgent01.sinks.sparkStream.hostname = edge01
TwitterAgent01.sinks.sparkStream.port = 9999
TwitterAgent01.sinks.sparkStream.channel = MemoryChannel01

TwitterAgent01.channels.MemoryChannel01.type = memory
TwitterAgent01.channels.MemoryChannel01.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent01.channels.MemoryChannel01.transactionCapacity = 10000
```

Flume and spark submission are in the same server, I'm able to telnet port 9999 from itself.

For additional info, I've added some required library in flume and spark directory
$FLUME_HOME/lib

```
spark-streaming-flume_2.11-2.2.0.jar
spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.11-2.2.0.jar
scala-library-2.11.8.jar
commons-lang3-3.5.jar
```

$SPARK_HOME/jars

```
spark-streaming-flume_2.11-2.2.0.jar
spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.11-2.2.0.jar
scala-library-2.11.8.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-lang3-3.5.jar
```

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Run your flume configuration with this added logging enabling parameters. -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -Dorg.apache.flume.log.printconfig=true -Dorg.apache.flume.log.rawdata=true          After that send the relevant bit of the logs for further discussion.

Comment: there's no additional log displayed on the screen. It was just the same as without any logging parameters. Btw, running jar file from my PC leads to the same result...spark streaming is not receiving any data. It looks like it only works if I run the program manually from Eclipse (Run As - Scala Application).

Comment: I am facing a similar kind of issue, did you find the solution for it

Comment: not yet. I ended up working without spark streaming and process the data directly from Flume's output. This leads to some drawback situation but there's no other way...